# In Blackberry's Application class what is the difference between hasEventThread() and isHandlingEvents()

Tags: blackberry

In Blackberry's Application class what is the difference between hasEventThread() and isHandlingEvents().  I'm just curious, because I have only found hasEventThread useful.

From BB's docs for Applicaiton:

public boolean hasEventThread()
Determines if this application has entered the event dispatcher.
Returns:
True if this application has entered the event dispatcher (i.e. has invoked Application.enterEventDispatcher()); otherwise, false.
isHandlingEvents

public final boolean isHandlingEvents()
Determines if this application has entered the event dispatch loop.
Returns:
True if the application has entered the event dispatch loop; otherwise, false.

My only guess is that isHandlingEvents most happen sometime after hasEventThread.  But is that really that useful?

Comment: Interesting - their javadocs are almost identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do exactly the same thing.  I'm not sure why they both exist; probably legacy code and they possibly did different things in the past.  But they've certainly converged as on now.